# Function overload with an expression as argument

Tags: typescript, overloading

```
function fun(is: true);
function fun(is: false);
function fun(is: boolean) {
  console.log('executed');
}

fun(true, ''); // ok
fun(false, 0); // ok
fun(1 > 0); // error
```

Actually I know that it is because we don't know before compilation what `1 > 0` will return but Can I in some way get rid of it?

I don't want to add the third overload `function fun(is: boolean);` because I have a case where the second parameter depends on the first.

```
function fun(is: true, secondParameter: number);
function fun(is: false, secondParameter: string);
function fun(is: boolean, secondParameter: number | string);
function fun(is: boolean) {
  console.log('executed');
}

fun(true, 0); // ok
fun(false, '0'); // ok
fun(1 > 0, '0'); // ok
fun(1 < 0, '0'); // ok
```

See the third and fourth call. That is what I want to avoid. I need protect types. If the first parameter is true, then the second has to be number, otherwise a string. Unfortunately when I need to call fun with an expression then it doesn't work

Comment: The problem here is that if you want to call the function with a dynamic value, that will be either `true` or `false` but it will not be known at compile time which it is. So if you want to handle unknown values, you will need to have an overload that can take either `number` or `string`

Comment: In this case I'll be able to call ```fun``` with appropriate set of arguments as I did in the third and fourth call. I thought that I'd be able to in some way fix it. The point is that the second parameter's type depends on the first.

Comment: The first set of overloads in the above don't make any sense. The second set show what you're trying to do. Suggest just removing the first set.

Comment: Sometimes the dependency can be checked at compile time, sometimes it can't. If you need dynamic expressions then it can't be checked at compile time

Comment: I think I'd just have `function funTrue(x: number)` and `function funFalse(x: string)` (but with better names). Clearer at both point of use and point of declaration, and can be statically checked.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't  agree, it's common to have overloads where if we pass one constant, the next parameter if of a type and if we pass another constant the next parameter is of another type. I am assuming this is a simplified example :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Not sure which comment you're replying to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, You're too fast for me :). The one where you say the first two overloads are not needed.

Comment: inappropriate set of arguments* (amendment for my previous comment). Ok guys, so unfortunately I can't do this. The only way is to add third overload which will destroy my type guardian or conditionally call one of these by ```if(1 > 0) fun(true, 0) else fun(false, '0')```

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - The first *set* of overloads (I should have said "the first code block", sorry -- and just *barely* missed the edit window :-) ). There are two code blocks, the first one just doesn't make any sense at all and obscures the real question, which is covered by the second code block.

Comment: You might find this post useful, you don't need all the overloads if you use conditional types

Comment: It seems that compiler infers the type of `1 < 0` as `boolean`, not `false`. I suppose it can't be avoided unless it's fixed in the compiler.